# how to clean this lint warning in c?

Tags: c, macros, lint

I have the following code:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_ROOMS

if((unsigned int)(NUMBER_OF_ROOMS - 2) > 20)
{
   // do something here
}
```

but I got a lint warning:`Warning 506: Constant value Boolean`, what does this mean and how to fix it?

Comment: writing such code with an empty macro is quite unusual and distracting. You should define `NUMBER_OF_ROOMS` to be `0` explicitly. If you want it to be unsigned, you should just use `2U` instead of `2` to be sure that this is `unsigned`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that the value of the expression is constant, and thus the `if` is pointless since it's known at compile-time whether or not it will be true or not.

You could of course make it more dynamic, or use the preprocessor instead:

```
#if (NUMBER_OF_ROOMS - 2) > 20
// do something here
#endif
```

I assumed the cast to `(unsigned int)` was pointless, if these really were values close to the boundaries of the integer precision, then Jens Gustedt's comment applies.

Comment: To change that to preprocessor computation correctly you'd have to be much more careful about the `unsigned` part. The preprocessor is supposed to compute in `[u]intmax_t`. I guess something like `(UINT_MAX & (NUMBER_OF_ROOMS - 2U)) > 20` should work.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the value of your `if` statement is known at compile-time.

The compiler just sees `if (30 - 2 > 20)` (plus an unneeded cast), which it doesn't need to evaluate at runtime.