# Lint Warning 506: prio3: Constant value Boolean

Tags: c, warnings, lint, pc-lint

When i run my code for lint, I am getting warnings saying that "Warning 506: Constant value Boolean" for the line where i am assigning a variable with Macro.

```
    #define FALSE   (0) 
    #define TRUE    (!FALSE)
    typedef char              BOOL;
    BOOL fTriggerCallback;

    fun_1()
    {
        fTriggerCallback = FALSE; //No warning
    }

    fun_2()
    {
       if(fTriggerCallback == FALSE)
         {
             fTriggerCallback =TRUE; //here is the warning
         }
    }

    fun_3()
    {
        fTriggerCallback =TRUE; //here is the warning
    }
```

In this code I am getting warnings where I assign TRUE to variable. Warnings are not seen where I assign the FALSE to variable.

But when I changed the Macro `#define TRUE 1` the warning is fixed. I dont know the exact cause/reason behind this.

Comment: Possibly relevant (and a google away) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110146/how-to-clean-this-lint-warning-in-c

Comment: I assume you're using an old or otherwise outdated C compiler, or you would be using [the standard bool functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean)?

Comment: Can you possibly show the usage, too?

Answer (score 2):

Lint is complaining because `TRUE` is expanded to `(!FALSE)` which is expanded to `(!0)`.  Error 506 flags:

> A Boolean, i.e., a quantity found in a context that requires a Boolean such as an argument to `&&` or `||` or an `if()` or `while()` clause or `!`, was found to be a constant and hence will evaluate the same way each time.

Lint is complaining about a logical operation (`!`) on an constant value (`0`).
If [C99's `stdbool.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean) is not available, read into [PC-lint's strong types](http://www.gimpel.com/html/strong.htm).